# Why can't I see Connections options in Watson Analytics?

Tags: connection, ibm-watson, dashdb

I'm an administrator of a Watson Analytics account. I deal with a huge amount of data that usually comes from a .csv file. The developers of the website where I get the .csv file shared with me a link to a Dash DB with all data, so I could connect my Watson Analytics to it. I researched about how to do that connection, but I found out that when I access my account settings I can't find the option for connections.

As I said, I'm the administrator of the account, so I don't understand why I can't access connections. Is necessary to have a special account to get that option in settings?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Data Connections panel is no longer available in the Account Settings pages.

To quote the [announcement](https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/watson-analytics-blog/upcoming-change-improving-the-data-connection-experience-in-watsonanalytics/),

> The new Data Connection process utilizes an IBM tool called Data Refinery. Unlike the previously used tool, Data Refinery will not be embedded in Watson Analytics. This means that administrators will need to register their IBM id with IBM Data Refinery outside of Watson Analytics, then when ready, will use this tool to initiate the ‘Data Flow’ from the relational database in question to Watson Analytics via IBM Data Refinery.

Please visit the announcement link for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, @user10209884 and @ mustaccio. I'll loof for this Data Refinery IBM tool to proceed.
You've been very helpful, thank you again!